# Como fazer para utilizar ActionBarActivity em aplicação que rode com android 2.2 ou maior?

Tags: java, android

Quero utilizar `Action Bar` em minha aplicação que vai rodar também em dispositivos com Android 2.2 ou maior. Sei que devo utilizar a Classe `ActionBarAcitivity`, que é a API disponibilizada pela Google. Já baixei o `Android Support Library` e `Repository` e importei a classe `android-support-v7-appcompat`. Nesta classe `android-support-v7-appcompat`  adicionei ao build path os `.jar` e adicionei estes `.jar` na minha classe que especializa `ActionBarActivity`.

Na tela principal fiz ela especializar e importar a `ActionBarActivity`, mas no `manifest` não consigo mudar do tema `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` para os temas da `ActionBarActivity` `android:theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"`.

Quando tento é gerado um erro:

> "Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with
>   value '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light').

Observações: Quando adiciono os `.jars` da `android-support-v7-appcompat` à minha classe, a classe `R` some.

Como fazer para utilizar a `ActionBarActivity` em aplicação que rode com Android 2.2 ou maior?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesta vídeo aula. http://www.thiengo.com.br/criando-suporte-actionbar-android-com-actionbarsherlock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após você criar um novo projecto, a melhor forma que achei no eclipse foi fazer:

> Arquivo->importar->código de Android existente->navegue ate "..\sdk\extras\android\support\v7"->seleccione o directório "appCompat"->Marque a opção "Copiar para a área de Trabalho"->terminar

Após fazer isso você terá um novo projecto com o nome `android-support-v7-appcompat`.

De seguida va para o projeto que você quer usar a biblioteca e:

> Clique o botão direito->propriedades->android->addicionar e ira aparecer o projecto que você importou acima, seleccione ele e já poderá ir ao manifest e mudar o Theme para `Theme.appCompat.Light`.

Se você vai trabalhar com as versões mais recentes também sugiro que você vá ao directório `values/styles.xml` e reescreva os themes para a `ActionBarCompat` e para as versões mais recentes assim:

```
<style name="MinhaAbCompat" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">


</style>

<style name="MinhaAbNormal" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

</style>
```

E assim você pode posteriormente customizar os seus temas tanto para as versões mais antigas como as mais antigas.

Comment: Ta certo Paulo. sem nenhum problema eu falo o PT-pt por isso assim a escrita. Valeu ai pela corecao.

Comment: Não sei ao certo o que eu estava fazendo de errado, ontem bati cabeça de mais com isso, mas hoje pela manhã fiz todos os passos novamente, juntando as dicas do Ramaral e as suas e deu tudo certo! Obrigado Paulo!

Answer (score 1):

Você para puder utilizar esse `Theme` tem que definir o `android:targetSdkVersion` no mínimo para API Level 11.

No entanto é aconselhável que `android:targetSdkVersion` aponte sempre para a API mais recente.

```
android:targetSdkVersion=19
```

Isto, além de resolver o problema do `Theme`, irá também resolver o problema do R e qualquer outros erros relacionados com `No resource found that matches the given name ....`

Eu também me deparei com este problema.
Quando encontrei a solução, fiz uma pergunta/resposta no [SO.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18429959/2556111)

Comment: Fazendo os testes aqui ramaral, por enquanto não obtive resultados. Talvez eu tenha deixado passar algum passo da configuração. Agradeço desde já a ajuda!

Comment: Ramaral suas dicas foram de grande valia, juntei as mesmas com as dicas do paulo e deu tudo certo. Não sei ao certo o que eu estava fazendo errado ou deixando de fazer, mas hoje pela manhã refiz todos os passos e obtive êxito. Obrigado mais uma vez Ramaral =)

Answer (score 0):

Use a biblioteca `ActionBarSherlock:`.

[ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Comment: Obrigado Carlos, mas consegui com a AppCompat mesmo!