# Como adicionar um ActionBar/ToolBar em projeto Android 2.2?

Tags: android

Tenho um projeto/app desenvolvido no Android 2.2. O mesmo roda sem problema algum, mas como os dispositivos atuais estão abolindo o botão "menu" ou em alguns caso usam botões virtuais, o mesmo  passou a ficar "deficiente" se for instalado em alguns dispositivos que não possuam o referido botão. Gostaria de saber como posso implementar uma ActionBar/ToolBar para esse projeto/app da forma mais simples possível, ou seja, não gostaria de ter que fazer grandes alterações no código.

Grato a todos e aguardo qualquer ajuda.

Ps.: A minha aplicação já existe, então não sei como incluir tal "recurso" na mesma.

Comment: Veja na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) e esta [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5555/2541)

Answer (score 0):

o código da Toobar no seu xml:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toobar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        />
```

Na classe da activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.seuLayout);
        toobar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toobar);
        setSupportActionBar(toobar);
}
```

Na styles.xml:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>       
 </style>
```